# Firestore: How to map data, to an array, from a document that contains an array of maps?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, mapping

I am self taught and very new, so please excuse any dumb questions.

I am trying to fetch a stored document using getDoc, map that data to an array, and use that array as data in a table. I believe I correctly stored my data as a document that contains an object(dataExcel) that contains an array of maps in Firestore.

```
const submitGrades = async () => {
    await setDoc(doc(db, 'EventData', 'Game 1' + ' PlayData'), {dataExcel})
    await setDoc(doc(db, "EventData", 'Game 1' + ' PlayerData'), {playerData})
  }
```

I know that this isn't ideal for complex querying, but it works for me as I have no problem pulling the entire document anyway. Then using JavaScript to sort the data the way I want. I am able get the document successfully using:

```
 const Fetch = async () => {
    const dataRef = doc(db, 'EventData', 'Game 1 PlayData');

    const data = await getDoc(dataRef);
    console.log(data);
  }
```

, however I can't figure out how to pull out the array of maps, set them in state and make them usable as data in a table.

[My current data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxYEi.png)

I need it to look like this once passed to a table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQFvO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if you do `data.data()` your document will be converted to a javscript object with all the fields that you have defined in firestore. Then, you can take that javascript object and fill your table.